# How to timeout if connection not establish

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Is there any default timeout value that after a number of tries if connection not establish then i got timeout from socket.io API ? in my application i try to connect with Nodejs server using socket.io but if connection not establish or unreachable i want that at least i get some event after x number of tries and then i should inform a user that there is a connection problem with server. but some how my client continuously trying to connect with a server and print the following exception on console:

```
socket.io-1.3.5.js:2 GET https://chatapp.local:8898/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1485528658982-172 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here is my code:

```
  socket = io(socketUrl, {'force new connection': true});

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        uiHandler("socket.connect");
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        uiHandler("socket.error", {error: err});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        uiHandler("socket.disconnect");
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        uiHandler("socket.end");
    });
```

How i can set a timeout if connection not establish within 30sec. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the API docs you can set the timeout value and the number of retries on each connection, so if you want to try for 30 seconds you basically have

```
maxTime = timeout * reconnectionAttempts
```

Please note that you have a delay between each retry (which default to 1000 ms) and a randomization factor.If you want to have total control over the duration before emitting a *ConnectionError* to your clients you will have to tinker with them a little bit.

From the API docs you can also see that each time an a connection fail an error is emitted as either *connect_timeout* or *connection_error*. If every available attempts fail then a *reconnect_failed* will be fired. Then you will be able to tell your user that something went wrong.

In a more general way you have several options to implement a control over an asynchronous process. Two come to mind immediately : promises and observables. You might want to explore them for a more general & extensible approach.

Please feel free to ask in the comms if you want more details or if I do not answer properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Well there is a reconnect_failed event as well if connection not established after number of attempts . Here is a link: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/705